# How to debounce the observer function in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to listen to the onScroll event in angular 2 and I've created the following code which works, however every scroll event is calling next and it's hitting browser performance. I was hoping that the observer.next function would be very lightweight and debouncing at the subscriber would be enough but either it isn't very lightweight or I'm doing something wrong. Can someone help me to debounce effectively?

```
import {Component, Renderer, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Subject, Observable, Observer} from "rxjs";
@Component({
selector: 'heading',
templateUrl: './heading.component.html',
styles: [require('./heading.component.scss')]
})

export class HeadingComponent implements OnInit {

observable: Observable<Event>;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.observable = new Observable<Event>(
        (observer: Observer<Event>) => {
            this.renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'scroll', (evt: Event) => {
                observer.next(evt);
        })
        }
    );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.observable
        .debounceTime(400)
        .subscribe(
            (evt: Event) => console.log('next event' + evt),
            (err: string) => console.error(err),
            () => console.info('done')
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the correct way to do this was actually as follows ( thanks to Dzmitry & Ryan from angular gitter )

```
constructor() {
    this.observable = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
        .debounceTime(400)
        .map(() => window.scrollY)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `.debounceTime(400)` replace it with `.debounce(400)`.

See docs : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/debounce.md

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however when I try to just call debounce(400) I get a typescript compilation error - Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type'(value: Event)...
I tried changing the types from Event to any with the same results